How did Jason Bourne know the garbage man isn't CIA?
Just like Simon Ross, I also thought this bin man was undercover CIA. How's Jason Bourne so cocksure the bin man isn't affiliated any way with the CIA?

Simon Ross : Oh, the bin man. I think he's one of them.
Jason Bourne : The garbage man? Negative.
Simon Ross : Oh, Jesus. Jesus! He's reaching for something.





He gave him an ocular pat-down, and cleared him for passage.

Maybe because he's already pre-emptively taken out the CIA's bin man and all their other operatives.

Ok first of all from a meta perspective... That's what you were supposed to think.
Like the moment Jason Bourne looks around and sees a team of 2 suspiciously looking dudes you're supposed to feel paranoid and disoriented. They constantly switch perspectives so that you don't know where you are, they show you lots of suspicious people or those whom you could think look suspicious, they intercut it with HQ footage, confirming that the threat is real and immanent.
So as someone not trained in these situations you're supposed to be paranoid and disoriented, while Jason Bourne who has been trained for that, both scans the crowd for adversaries as well as mapping out the effective angles of the cameras and how not to be seen. So in other words, despite the chaos, he's still calm and in control of the situation.
So medium threat level. The situation is dangerous, but not yet seriously concerning. So far everything is going according to plan. Then the bin man appears, which to someone in a paranoid state of mind means "Oh shit! That's it, there are no coincidences: I'm screwed".
You might even go through checking him out for yourself. He's wearing uniform, but that's actually just a vest that he could drop to blend in, he's walking straight towards Simon Ross' character, he's grabbing something, he even wears gloves (though I think continuity screwed up here, because he only does that in the shot where he picks up something...). So the people making the movie give you some good reasons to feel scared by him.
But realistically that's feeding into your confirmation bias. You're expecting a catastrophe involving a killer and you're given a scenario that could be that, so you're taking that.
On the other hand Jason Bourne has already scanned and observed a bunch of the actual killers. Blue jeans, brown leather jackets, rather casual and unremarkable outfits (not worth much when described by a witness and comfortable for fighting and running), short hair or bold (military background?), middle aged, groups of 2 people that belong together but look in different directions, some having ear pieces or talking to their sleeves...
So he has a pretty good idea of the type of people that were sent to get Simon Ross.
So while the bin man would make a perfect assassin under different circumstances (perfectly visible, but no one pays any attention to him) he doesn't really fit the profile. He's working alone and he's in disguise (while the rest looks like they're dropped off on short notice) rather than casual.
Also the timing is TOO perfect. Like the rest of the bunch are still walking around in the train station looking out for their person of interest (haven't seen him once!) in this crowded environment. While the bin man found him without any searching? Inside the crowd (where looking for someone is damn near impossible)? Coming prepared for the both the job as a bin man and an assassin? Already being at the place, while the other folks literally just hastily entered the building? Walking SLOWLY and almost straight towards the target. Almost keeping eye contact, which could both be a giveaway (a former potential operative revealed that he isn't by looking away eventually) and be unprofessional. That is pulling ... like what? A gun? In a crowded train station in London? Like even with the movie magic of silencers (the others don't even have silenced weapons) perfectly silencing a shot, he would instantly give away his cover and make this an international incident. While the rest upon locating their target rather follow or direct their target to a less populated area despite being in kill distance to them.
Like for the sake of the movie, the bin man could be an operative for a different agency that already knew about the meeting ahead of the CIA and came prepared (and is unaware of the rest), but while the disguise as a bin man would generally fit (though not sure if in the setting of a train station with massive surveillance, he wouldn't still need to act weird to stay covert once he acted), he would use a completely different mode of operation with respect to the rest, which is unlikely for one agency.
So no Jason Bourne has good reason to suspect he's not one of the guys, that he already spotted and identified as threats and he has good reason to assume that wandering through the crowd is not an effective way of searching for someone and that being geared up for a cleaning job is too much attention to detail for an operation that apparently has just commenced on short notice.
Or you could look the other way around and look at him as a bin cleaner and try to find evidence confirming that. Idk age, haircut, whether his attire is in general practical for combat (like he wears gloves, but the kind of garden gloves, not your slick leather which might make operating a fire arm unnecessarily difficult), whether he's in shape, whether his behavior and attire fits the job or whether it's a hasty disguise, etc.
Now that Jason Bourne is able to do that in a split second is while I'd have to rewind the tape several times, is "training", by which I mean mostly movie magic. Sure if you can train such situations and remain calmer and more alert than people who don't which allows you to perceive things, but like with many movie things, it's usually a grain of truth that is "slightly" exaggerated.

Bourne has a near-superhuman skill as a 'super-evaluator'. He has the ability to assess a complex scene within seconds, identify the risks, sightlines and exit-strategies all while still carrying out his primary goals.

MARIE: You're paranoid. You were shot. It's natural.
[She's not listening. He leans in. Flat out now.]
BOURNE: I can tell you the license plate
numbers of all three cars out
front. I can tell you that the
waitress is left-handed and the guy
at the counter weighs two-hundred
and fifteen pounds and knows how to
handle himself. I know that the
best, first place to look for a gun
is the cab of that grey truck
outside. I know that at this
altitude I can run flat out for
half a mile before I lose my edge.
I knew that you were my first, best
option out of Zurich? How do I
know all that? How can I know all
that and not know who I am? How is
that possible?
The Bourne Identity

As to precisely what about the binman tips Bourne off that he's not a threat, that probably comes down to a combination of his gait, his clothing, his haircut, any injuries that he's carrying (like a bad back), etc etc. that are consistent with what you'd expect to see in a sanitorial engineer in his 40s.
We're just supposed to believe that Bourne has this ability to see all this in a single glance, without it needing further explanation.

I agree, though I'll point out that the most significant factor is the things the bin/garbage man looks at.  His wheeled cart and the next bin to empty?  Or looking at the people within the space, and locating the exits/entrances?  Travelers will look at the walls with signs and listings of train schedules.  Plus, pairs of operatives will look in opposite directions to scan the area efficiently while pairs of travelers will together look at the same thing - wall screens, newspaper kiosks, and destination doorways.

@SottoVoce - Aye. There are a hundred "tells" that a skilled noticer would notice. We don't see them because we're not CIA trained super-soldiers. At least you're not. My status is classified.

Of course we don't know whether the movie actually included enough details for a skilled noticer to realistically notice or not notice, because we don't know whether the producers had hired a skilled consultant. Or at least you don't know, I'm not at liberty to say whether I know.

Simply experience and, in the script, it's made clear that Bourne is scoping out the crowd for agents already.

BOURNE on the periphery looking out across the throng, picking out the inconsistencies.


Your answer just raises more questions. from " looking out across the throng", how did Bourne see that garbage man isn't CIA? what was consistent, or inconsistent, about garbage man that proved he isn't CIA?

Nothing. He's experienced enough to rule him out. There's not much they can show in a split second appearance.

Eth, you, being the untrained unwashed masses, do not have the training of mr bourne, so that shot is merely reinforcing the gulf, the difference, between those who have trained for this (mr Bourne), and those who have not, including Mr Ross and presumably yourself (apologies if you are a trained assassin, though). Bourne is trained to look out for lots of different details (you get a sense of this in the first film), the actual details of which would be too much to put in a movie, just suffice to say 'Bourne knows who's bad, Mr Ross (and the audience) do not' ...and this leads to Ross' demise

Most people in the 'bad guy' position on a movie like this are not going to look like Mr garbage man at all, not by a long shot, and part of that is what is required to keep fit and constantly trained and prepared for that role. Mr garbage man doesnt have anything visual about him that says he has any training. Sometimes it obvious, from the shoes you wear, the clothes you wear, how you wear them, how they fit, their cut on you, even your haircut, your walking gait, your standing stance, your breathing, your movement, all visual clues. Usually these guys are clearly ex-military.
